# Retain Bash suffix while stripping tailing string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to retain the last 5 characters of a string and then remove the last character thereafter. I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this with Bash.

The string example would be **"0101234567"**. I want to preserve only **4567** without the final quotation mark. If I use the code example below, it returns **4567"**.

```
while IFS="," read v1 v2 v3 v4 ; do
echo "$v1,$v2,${v3: -5},$v4"
done < $FILE1 > $FILE2
```

I have also tried:

```
while IFS="," read v1 v2 v3 v4 ; do
echo "$v1,$v2,${v3:(-5)(%?)},$v4"
done < $FILE1 > $FILE2
```

Comment: Are you sure your string has double-quotes preserved?

Comment: Looks like you are parsing CSV, don't do this in shell, it's a very hard language to program on. Better to switch to python.

Comment: Yeah it's a CSV export from a customer. I don't know Python lol. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start would be to use `bash` [parameter-expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to find the substring.

Assuming you preserve the double-quotes and know the *start* and the *length* of the sub-string you want to extract, you can do it as

```
start=7
len=4

echo "${v3:start:len}"
```

You can make the variables configurable depending on your input string. E.g.

```
v3="\"0101234567\""
echo "${v3:start:len}"
4567
```